# Testing a user script with sh

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sh, userscripts

I have a userscript (hopefully cross-browser compatible, though at the moment I'm running it on Tampermonkey) and I'm trying to set up a test suite. 
Or rather, trying to see if the approach I took in creating a test suite was reasonable and if I should/could do it differently.

The userscript is pretty straightforward: define a bunch of functions, then call one of them to do its work. To check it in `<a href="https://nodejs.org/">node</a>`, I want to define the functions but avoid running the initial function (since there isn't a browser present to handle the DOM properties). So I run this ugly shell script (hopefully fairly compatible; I'm running it on `dash`):

```
#!/bin/dash
grep -ev '^\s*stuff\s*\(\s*\)\s*;?\s*($|//)' oeis-tools.user.js > test-cat.js
./getFunctions.sh >> test-cat.js
cat test.js >> test-cat.js
nodejs test-cat.js
rm test-cat.js
```

So basically I drop the line where the function is invoked, `cat` it with a test script, then pass it to node.
Within the test script I have an assert-like function

```
function shouldBe(func, args, desiredResults) {
    totalTests++;
    tested.push(func.name);
    var actualResult = func.apply(null, args);
    if (isIn(actualResult, desiredResults)) return;
    console.log('Called ' + func.name + '(' + args.map(disp).join(', ') + ')');
    if (desiredResults.length === 1) {
        console.log('\tExpected ' + disp(desiredResults[0]));
    } else {
        console.log('\tExpected ' + desiredResults.map(disp).join(' or '));
    }
    console.log('\tGot      ' + disp(actualResult));
    failedTests++;
}
```

which lets me call tests in the form `shouldBe(functionToTest, [firstInput, secondInput, etc], [correctOutput, otherCorrectOutput])`.
(I've left out the definitions of various helper functions but their precise definitions shouldn't matter here.)

On the plus side, this lets me write tests quickly and leaves the userscript untouched (no testing baggage). But it seems pretty hacky. Is there a better approach?

Comment: What do you mean by DOM properties? Could you post the code to the function whose call you're removing via this script? There might be a way to simulate or shim the DOM properties you're requesting.

Comment: @Compynerd255: It's sort of long, and very messy as the underlying page is tag soup. In fact this is kind of the point -- that site is slated to be redesigned soon, and I'm going to have to rewrite all the DOM-related code. But I'm not too worried about errors in that part, most of the errors happen in the more interesting parts which I have separated from the DOM-related code (really more because it was the right thing to do rather than for the purpose of testing, but that's a convenient side effect).

Comment: @Compynerd255: If you'd really like I can dump the file (about a thousand lines) to pastebin or the like, but I don't want to scare off people who see giant code and think I'm asking them to debug it. :)

Comment: @Compynerd255: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/5JSr20tP

Comment: @Compynerd255: And here's the test code: http://pastebin.com/aLQG23iG

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** (Changed answer from recommendation of putting test functions in separate file)

Since the existence of the DOM is a precondition of your `stuff()` function, you could wrap the call you make at the end in an `if` statement that checks for the existence of the `DOM`.

```
if (document) {
    stuff();
}
```

Or, better yet, since the function is only being called in one place,

```
if (document) {
    /* code of stuff() */
}
```

Comment: It's a user script, so it needs to be in a single file to work.

Comment: @Charles Edited answer to support single file execution.